# How to add radio group button in preference xml in android in one row?

Tags: android

I'm trying from this xml and want to add radio button but not getting solution .
Here i am not getting proper solution .so suggest me . 
Here also attach image which type UI iwant from using Preference screen.

```
    <Preference

        android:key="@string/pref_key_passcode_toggle"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/check_custom"
        android:title="@string/passcode_turn_on" />

    <Preference
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        android:key="@string/pref_key_change_passcode"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:title="@string/passcode_change_passcode"

        />
    <Preference
        android:height="40dp"
        android:key="@string/pref_key_change_password"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:title="@string/password_change"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

[image: I want to get this image type UI using only preference xml .]

Comment: Could you add a little bit more detail about what is not working?  Are you getting an error?  The XML you posted is not well-formed - could that be a problem?

Comment: hello killthrush, 
here I update my quetion and get idea.

Comment: cool, glad you're getting some answers - thanks for clarifying.  If the answer helps you, please remember to upvote it and mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All EXISTING preferences can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html). If you're not too picky on showing all the options at all times, you can use ListPreference. It will only show the currently selected option in the layout. When the user selects it, a dialog will be shown displaying the list of all options to choose from.

If you truly want it to look like the image above, you'll need to extends Preference and implement your own MultiSelectPreference. You can specify your own layout and use standard widgets to design it exactly how you want it to look.